# Vertical center divs within floats

Tags: html, css

I have two columns within a `.container div`: they are `percentage` widths and floated `left`. I need the content of these floats to be vertical and horizontally centered. They are dynamic heights, and may change. I would like to avoid jQuery. Would anyone know a simple method?

http://jsfiddle.net/LnMPC/2/

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 400px;
}
.col40 {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
.col60 {
    width: 60%;
    float: left;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    width: 13em;
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col40">
        <p>40% -- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet illo ab temporibus consequuntur excepturi sint delectus laboriosam aspernatur quas tenetur corporis error consequatur tempore eos minus asperiores voluptatum alias quibusdam!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col60">
        <p>60% -- Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus vel dolorum. Quos atque deleniti fuga quo consequuntur molestias beatae voluptates magni architecto ducimus inventore exercitationem voluptatum nostrum. Labore culpa modi.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks — is there a way to make sure the .container is always 100%  height of the browser window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display:table` is the new trend to avoid `float`s as you need to `clear` them later :)

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LnMPC/4/)

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.container {
    width: 600px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 400px; /* or "100%" if container needs to be full-height*/
    display:table;        /* added*/
}
.col40 {
    width: 40%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    display:table-cell;        /* added*/
    vertical-align:middle;        /* added*/
}
.col60 {
    width: 60%;
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;        /* added*/
    vertical-align:middle;        /* added*/
}
p {
    width: 13em;
    margin:0 auto; /* added to center the content*/
    text-align:center;        /* added - optional */
    background-color: salmon;
}
```

Comment: Here is the Summary from above's solutions :D I recommend to go for that one.

Comment: @Sven : already upvoted your answer but **your solution lacks the horizontal center part** ...which i have added....no need to make a comparison fella!! :)

Comment: This is good, but when I also add ` width: 100%;` to the container, it seems to remove the 100% height?

Comment: @tmyie : looks fine in fiddle...if you show your fiddle then i might be able to help you out!! :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. I misunderstood my own code. It appears when I insert an image into a column, it removes the 100% height?

Comment: It's not an a fiddle, but you could inspect element: http://tomjhume.com/php/how/main/splash-page.php

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45638/discussion-between-noobeditor-and-tmyie)

Answer (score 1):

CSS

```
.container{
display:table;
}
.col40,.col60{
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.col40{
width:40%;
}
.col60{
width:60%;
}
```

If you want to horizontally center, they are already totalling 100% (40+60) so I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

http://jsfiddle.net/LnMPC/5/

I guess this is what you want, right?

```
p {
    width: 13em;
    background-color: salmon;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```